# Integration testing EF Core + AutoMapper ProjectTo

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, automapper

I'm trying to integration test a service class that uses AutoMapper and the ProjectTo extension method. In the application itself, I am injecting an IMapper via ASP.Net Core's built-in DI framework. All of this seems to be configured correctly as the app itself works. For example, my service class resembles this

```
public class MyServiceClass
{
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;
    private readonly MyDbContext _context;
    public MyServiceClass(IMapper mapper, MyDbContext context)
    {
        _mapper = mapper;
        _context = context;
    }

    public MyModelDto GetMyModel()
    {
        var myModelDto = _context.MyModels.ProjectTo<MyModelDto>().FirstOrDefault();
        return myModelDto;
    }
}
```

Now, I want to integration test this service i.e. new it up in an Xunit test (without ASP.Net DI framework since it's a unit test project) and have it actually run the query against a test database. My unit test looks something like this

```
public class MyServiceClassTests
{
    [Fact]
    public void GetMyModelTest()
    {
        // Arrange
        var context = new MyDbContext();
        var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.AddProfile<MyModelProfile>();
        });
        var mapper = new Mapper(config);
        var sut = new MyServiceClass(mapper, context);

        // Act
        var results = sut.GetMyModel();

        // Assert
        Assert.NotNull(results);
    }
}
```

I get the following exception:

```
Error Message:
 System.InvalidOperationException : Mapper not initialized.
 Call Initialize with appropriate configuration. 
If you are trying to use mapper instances through a container or otherwise,
 make sure you do not have any calls to the static Mapper.Map methods,
 and if you're using ProjectTo or UseAsDataSource extension methods,
 make sure you pass in the appropriate IConfigurationProvider instance.
```

Emphasis on **if you're using ProjectTo or UseAsDataSource extension methods, make sure you pass in the appropriate IConfigurationProvider instance.**

Of course, I don't want to change all of my uses of ProjectTo<> to pass in an IConfigurationProvider, I want to continue using the parameterless version. There's something that the services.AddAutoMapper() extension is doing that is not being replicated when I construct my own instance of IMapper in my unit test.

Is there anything I can do to make this work the way I think it ought to work?

Comment: [The docs](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection#projectto-usage). As your tests, the latest version of the extension doesn't use the static mapper anymore.

Comment: Why you are injecting/passing `IMapper` to the service class if you are not using it inside? The code looks incorrect even for normal case. `services.AddAutoMapper()` probably initializes the static global `Mapper`, but again, why you are injecting `IMapper` instance if not using it? Anyway, you can change your test to use `Mapper.Initialize` and `Mapper.Instance`, but the better approach would be to update your services to use `IMapper.ProjectTo` rather than the `ProjectTo` extension method.